# PHP webpush library (Minishlink\WebPush) no event.data

Tags: php, push-notification, payload, web-push

I have configured webpush and all is going well... I have registered the service-worker.js, can request permission, save the subscription to my db and send a push notification from the server using the library which is installed.

When I send the push notification

```
    [
        'subscription' => Subscription::create($subs_arr),
        'payload' => '{"title":"test title","msg":"Hello World!", "icon":"https://www.newhomesforsale.co.uk/media/chevron.png","url":"https://www.newhomesforsale.co.uk/"}'
    ]
];
```

I get a success message:

```
[v] Message sent successfully for subscription https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send/e2JHJ2YcIfM:APA91bHwU7CruFTDkpAH-zbnJRNhvJEK-mCze2hFNa48mdK8pk-oWuXJUn57Ai9Nw0d-skviCfJ40g1yX7qWKucGHPF3jeNyhkJfZ-8kpxYJNQowrAR561b0dQZJAseL_eBsJRMrxnDP.
```

and a push message appears in the browser - great.

The problem I have is that the service-worker file doesn't seem to see the payload information because the message displays even as simply

```
Oh No - no data {"isTrusted": true}
```

Service-worker file:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        return;
    }

    const sendNotification = body => {
        // you could refresh a notification badge here with postMessage API
        const title = "Web Push example";

        return self.registration.showNotification(title, {
            body,
        });
    };

    if (event.data) {
        const message = event.data.text();
        event.waitUntil(sendNotification(message));
    } else {
        do_serverlog('Push event but no data');
        sendNotification("Oh No - no data" + JSON.stringify(event));
    }
});
```

Would be great to get the last piece of the puzzle to figure out how to correctly send/read the payload.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that I made a mistake passing throught the keys into the subscription ($subs_arr).

It seems that if you have provide the endpoint, but not the keys, the push notification still works, but with the data stripped out. This sidetracked me as I had assumed that it wouldn't work at all if the keys were missing.

I thought maybe this might help someone at some point.